# To remove quotes in a dataframe column of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

need assistance with something i think i pretty minor but cant seem to find a way around.

```
twitter_df['Split Tweets'] = twitter_df['Tweets'].apply(lambda x:(x.split())).astype(str).str.lower()
```

the above returns the desired result but i cant find a way around getting the quotation marks '.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ROFR.png)

I need just the commas (,) to separate the string NOT quotation marks(')

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the separator, if you are separating by comma then you need to specify

```
twitter_df['Split Tweets'] = twitter_df['Tweets'].apply(lambda x:(x.split(','))).astype(str).str.lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the quotation marks show that these are lists of strings. If you do anything with the elements of these lists (such as print or concatenate), the quotation marks will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @ibadia and @Engensmax

the below worked:

```
twitter_df['Split Tweets'] = twitter_df['Tweets'].apply(lambda x:(x.split()))

twitter_df['Split Tweets'] =  twitter_df[['Split Tweets']]
```